# fixing bug to make 'width' value responsive

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I am integrating design that has over 20 Js scripts loaded into a Drupal theme and run into a bug with the 'width' value not being responsive in my theme while it is in the original design I am converting from. In my theme I can see:

```
width: 470px;
```

In the original design, I see:

```
width: 457.234375px;
```

I have verified that all CSS and JS are loading. How is dynamic size usually set? Is this jQuery or CSS thing? How would you approach finding the issue? What would you look for? Any tools that may be more useful. Currently, I use Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools
Thank You

Comment: That looks like it is set from JS code. So the place to check would be your JS files that do a `.css(..)` or `.style.width = ..` or so..

Comment: Probably a js plugin that is setting the width inline thus your css can't override.

Comment: Can you be certain that your value isn't overridden?
Browser debuggers often show the calculated width in pixels, when the CSS width is set in `em` or percentages. But they will also tell you which CSS selector is responsible for the result.
If a javascript is responsible for the width, you will probably see a value for width in the style attribute.

Comment: Thank You all for suggestions. It was missing an extra Css class in the body tag. your comments will be useful next time i am in the same situation. Thanks